# Creating an nginx-rtmp cluster

Tags: nginx, streaming, rtmp

I've created an nginx-rtmp server where several IP cameras can direct their video-stream. I want to expand this to a cluster that can auto-scale. Normally clusters have some load-balancer with a fixed ip-address that redirects traffic to different hosts in the cluster.

I am not sure how to setup something similar for nginx-rtmp. Any new stream that points to the fixed address will need to be directed to the same host.

Can anyone explain how to setup something like this? Even some links where I can read more about this would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Normally I setup clusters for large concurrent streaming. For example 1 origin and 10 edges.

So why you need so many server accepting incoming RTMP ?

A streaming server can easily accept 5000 incoming rtmp if network bandwidth not an issue.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Im new to streaming world so I hope this question makes sense.

With a growing number of stream, will you eventually need multiple origins? If the multiple origins are behind some DNS (e.g. https://live.myapp.com) -  what is the correct way to setup the cluster so that one stream continuously is directed to the same origin?

Answer (score 1):

Nginx Cluster, or expanding Nginx RTMP capabilities involves bellow aspects:

- Supporting many streams, such as 10,000 push streams.
- Supporting many playback streams, such as 100,000 client playbacks.
- Supporting HLS playback cluster, see [this post](https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v5/doc/nginx-for-hls)

To expand push streams, you can use multiple independent Nginx RTMP source servers and load balance using different apps. For example, if each Nginx RTMP supports 3,300 streams, you can use three Nginx RTMP servers with different apps for load balancing. The configuration is as follows:

```
# For Nginx Server 1
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;

        application live1 {
            live on;
        }
    }
}
```

```
# For Nginx Server 2
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;

        application live2 {
            live on;
        }
    }
}
```

To expand playback, you can choose to use the SRS Edge Server. For example, deploying 30 SRS Edge servers, each supporting 3,300 playbacks, can support approximately 100,000 playback clients. The configuration is as follows:

```
vhost __defaultVhost__ {
    cluster {
        mode            remote;
        origin          nginx-server-ip:1935;
    }
}
```

For more details, you can refer to [this link](https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v5/doc/edge).